# Add missing rows to data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table, cross-join

Let's say that my options of values are 1 to 9. 
I have the following data.table:

```
> group = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4)
> value = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,4,6,7,4,9)
> a=data.table(group=group,value=value)
> a
    group value
 1:     1     2
 2:     1     3
 3:     1     4
 4:     2     5
 5:     2     6
 6:     2     7
 7:     2     8
 8:     3     2
 9:     3     4
10:     3     6
11:     3     7
12:     4     4
13:     4     9
```

Now for every group, I want to add the missing rows. I.e. for group 1, I miss values 1 and 5-9. However, if I do it with CJ:

```
> b=a[CJ(group=group,value=value,unique=TRUE),on=.(group,value)]
> b
    group value
 1:     1     2
 2:     1     3
 3:     1     4
 4:     1     5
 5:     1     6
 6:     1     7
 7:     1     8
 8:     1     9
 9:     2     2
10:     2     3
11:     2     4
12:     2     5
13:     2     6
14:     2     7
15:     2     8
16:     2     9
17:     3     2
18:     3     3
19:     3     4
20:     3     5
21:     3     6
22:     3     7
23:     3     8
24:     3     9
25:     4     2
26:     4     3
27:     4     4
28:     4     5
29:     4     6
30:     4     7
31:     4     8
32:     4     9
    group value
```

I miss the value 1. As it is not in this data table at all. But I still consider it as one of my options. How can I do this?

Comment: `CJ(group = a[, unique(group)], value = seq_len(a[, max(value)]))`

Comment: Great! I do also have more columns in my original data.table, which I would like to keep, and insert NA for the newly generated rows. Is that also possible with this approach?

Comment: Just use `value = seq_len(max(value))` instead of `value` in your `CJ()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in @Roland's comment, instead of `value = value` in `CJ()`, use:

```
value = seq_len(max(value))
```

Or specify the range you would like in your `value` column.

Thus, you simply need to modify your attempt from being:

```
b = a[CJ(group = group, value = value, unique = TRUE), on = .(group,value)]
```

to being:

```
b = a[CJ(group = group, value = seq_len(max(value)), unique = TRUE),
      on = .(group,value)]
```

Comment: Works perfect. That I didn't think of this myself! Thanks